# How to calculate percentage of matching values on two arraylists?

Tags: java, arrays, percentage

i want to calculate percentage of matching values on two ArrayList's.

let say, if i have two arraylists as below, named `actual` and `required`.

```
ArrayList<String> actual = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> required = new ArrayList<String>();
```

- `actual` arraylist containing the values of `Programming, Appium, Jenkins, Selenium, Software Testing`
- `required` arraylist containing the values of `Appium, Jenkins, Selenium, protractor,API automation`

Now i want find the percentage of values match on these two lists. Any suggestion/solution appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or where you wave the problem, with the algorytm or the implementation? Simply you have two parts: compute number of items in both lists and compute the percentage based on item count.

Comment: Apply a counter variable and increment it if one of the elements of the first list is contained in the second list. That would require an iteration of the first list. Afterwards, you would need to calculate the percentage by using the resulting counter value and the size of the list that represents the 100%.

Comment: You can use Collection#retainAll() to create array with elements from both lists only, then take their size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<String> actual = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> required = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> common = new ArrayList<>(actual);
common.retainAll(required);

System.out.println(" 100.0 * common / actual = " + (actual.size() == 0 ? 0 : 100.0 * common.size() / actual.size()));
System.out.println(" 100.0 * common / required = " + (required.size() == 0 ? 0 : 100.0 * common.size() / required.size()));
```